# Rendering the decision tree as a step function

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I am trying to fit a decision tree on a data with only one explanatory variable and both explanatory and response variables are continuous. I believe in such case the result tree is almost like a step function as in a constant prediction value will be assigned for each subinterval of the horizontal axis. Most of the plotting functions for a tree would render the tree itself, but I am looking for a graphical representation of the tree in the form of the aforementioned step function. I believe this would require extracting the location of each leaf node and the range its corresponding prediction value would be in.

I am currently using the `rpart` and `rpart.plot` packages. While the latter offers a really great method `rpart.rules` which shows directly from which range on the x-axis each prediction value would be, it seems to have a limit on the maximum number of rules before it returns an error. My data would require the tree to be really deep and therefore downright simplifying would not be an option.

I am looking for a solution to bypass this limit or an alternative method that allows me to render this step function. A reproducible example using `rpart.rules` is given below:

```
library(rpart.plot)
set.seed(1)

x <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(1))
esp <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(0.25))
Y_noerror <- -1 + 0.5 * x
Y <- Y_noerror + esp
linear_data <- data.frame(Y = Y, x = x)

linear_tree <- rpart(Y ~ x,
                     data = linear_data,
                     control = rpart.control(cp = 0, minbucket = 2))

rpart.rules(linear_tree)
```

Comment: You could simply construct a dataset with equal increments, and plot the respective predictions

Comment: Indeed, isn't there a `predict` function for the `rpart` class that does exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the relevant information from `linear_tree$splits[,"index"]`, which gives you the `x` values at which your tree splits, i.e., at which there are steps. Then evaluate your tree within each step (plus once before the first and once after the last step), and plot:

```
steps_at <- sort(linear_tree$splits[,"index"])
xx <- c(min(steps_at)-1,
    rowMeans(cbind(head(steps_at,-1),tail(steps_at,-1))), # middle of each step
    max(steps_at)+1)
values <- predict(linear_tree,newdata=data.frame(x=xx)) # y value of each step

plot(range(xx),range(values),type="n",xlab="x",ylab="Y",las=1)
lines(c(min(xx),rep(steps_at,each=2),max(xx)),
    rep(values,each=2),type="l")
```

[image: step function]

Comment: It looks more like a tree flower bud or a pine cone than a tree.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But to my understanding, not all the entries in the `index` column are leaf nodes, so shouldn't it only be the leaf nodes that are evaluated?

Comment: The leaf nodes alone don't tell the entire story. Suppose you first split at $x=0.5$, then split the two branches again, once at $x=0.25$ and once at $x=0.75$. You get steps at $0.25$, $0.5$ and $0.75$, but the leaves are only $0.25$ and $0.75$. You do need to consider all splits.

Comment: Oh yea that makes sense